# AQL can not find row by PK. Row is there when selecting

Tags: aerospike

I have a namespace and a set in aerospike with information inside.
After performing a `SELECT * FROM mytecache.search_results` I get around 600 rows of this:

```
"bdee9a37e3217f28a057b5e0ebbef43f_Sabre_13"    | "a:11:{s:5:"price";a:14:{s:5:"total";d:2947.5999999999999;s:11:"pricePerPax";d:1473.8;s:8:"totalflt";d:2947.5999999999999;s:9:"baseprice";d:1901.0799999999999;s:3:"tax";d:986.51999999999998;s:10:"servicefee";i:60;s:11:"markupprice";d:1961.0799999999999;s | "flight_bdee9a37e3217f28a057b5e0ebbef43f" | 147380   | LIST('["LH", "LH", "LH", "LH"]'....
```

As you know, the first column is the primary key, so I try to select the row (which just appeared in SELECT) with:

```
aql> SELECT * FROM mytecache.search_results WHERE PK = "bdee9a37e3217f28a057b5e0ebbef43f_Sabre_13"
```

and I get:

```
Error: (2) AEROSPIKE_ERR_RECORD_NOT_FOUND
```

Explain returns this:

```
aql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM mytecache.search_results WHERE PK="bdee9a37e3217f28a057b5e0ebbef43f_Sabre_13"
+------------------+--------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------+--------+---------+----------+----------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+---------+
| SET              | DIGEST                                     | NAMESPACE   | PARTITION | STATUS | UDF     | KEY_TYPE | POLICY_REPLICA             | NODE              | POLICY_KEY              | TIMEOUT |
+------------------+--------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------+--------+---------+----------+----------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+---------+
| "search_results" | "6F62BE5323F0A51EF7DFDD5060A02E62CD2453F0" | "mytecache" | 623       | 2      | "FALSE" | "STRING" | "AS_POLICY_REPLICA_MASTER" | "BB9B25B63000056" | "AS_POLICY_KEY_DEFAULT" | 1000    |
+------------------+--------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------+--------+---------+----------+----------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.002 secs)
```

asinfo outputs:

```
1 :  node
     BB9B25B63000056
2 :  statistics
     cluster_size=1;cluster_key=883272F81547;cluster_integrity=true;cluster_is_member=true;uptime=1146;system_free_mem_pct=90;system_swapping=false;heap_allocated_kbytes=6525778;heap_active_kbytes=                                        6529792;heap_mapped_kbytes=6619136;heap_efficiency_pct=99;heap_site_count=14;objects=6191;tombstones=0;tsvc_queue=0;info_queue=0;delete_queue=0;rw_in_progress=0;proxy_in_progress=0;tree_gc_queue=0;                                        client_connections=19;heartbeat_connections=0;fabric_connections=0;heartbeat_received_self=7637;heartbeat_received_foreign=0;reaped_fds=47;info_complete=12326;proxy_retry=0;demarshal_error=0;early_                                        tsvc_client_error=0;early_tsvc_batch_sub_error=0;early_tsvc_udf_sub_error=0;batch_index_initiate=0;batch_index_queue=0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0;batch_index_complete=0;batch_index_error=0;batch_index_timeout=0                                        ;batch_index_unused_buffers=0;batch_index_huge_buffers=0;batch_index_created_buffers=0;batch_index_destroyed_buffers=0;batch_initiate=0;batch_queue=0;batch_error=0;batch_timeout=0;scans_active=0;qu                                        ery_short_running=0;query_long_running=0;sindex_ucgarbage_found=0;sindex_gc_locktimedout=0;sindex_gc_list_creation_time=39;sindex_gc_list_deletion_time=0;sindex_gc_objects_validated=11734;sindex_gc                                        _garbage_found=0;sindex_gc_garbage_cleaned=0;paxos_principal=BB9B25B63000056;migrate_allowed=true;migrate_partitions_remaining=0;fabric_bulk_send_rate=0;fabric_bulk_recv_rate=0;fabric_ctrl_send_rat                                        e=0;fabric_ctrl_recv_rate=0;fabric_meta_send_rate=0;fabric_meta_recv_rate=0;fabric_rw_send_rate=0;fabric_rw_recv_rate=0
3 :  features
     peers;cdt-list;cdt-map;pipelining;geo;float;batch-index;replicas-all;replicas-master;replicas-prole;udf
4 :  cluster-generation
     1
5 :  partition-generation
     0
6 :  build_time
     Sat Nov  4 02:19:49 UTC 2017
7 :  edition
     Aerospike Community Edition
8 :  version
     Aerospike Community Edition build 3.15.0.2
9 :  build
     3.15.0.2
10 :  services

11 :  services-alumni

12 :  build_os
     debian8
```

Which seems wrong. Why is the query not returning the result, when it is clearly there ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"As you know, the first column is the primary key,"  -- no first column is your first bin. The primary key is whatever you used to write the record. Aerospike does not store your primary key.

You are quite likely using a wrong PK for the record whose first bin is "bdee9a37e3217f28a057b5e0ebbef43f_Sabre_13"

https://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/aql/data_management.html

“STATUS” is the status of the operation. It will be the code as returned by the client for the record. E.g: 0 is AEROSPIKE_OK and 2 is AEROSPIKE_ERR_RECORD_NOT_FOUND.

So, even your explain execution in AQL is telling you in the STATUS that the record is not found.

Comment: To elaborate on the answer, my first bin's name was "PK" which caused the confusion.